# Dynamically update directive data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Sorry, maybe it's stupid question but i'm still learning.

I'm trying to make one simple line chart using D3.js in angularJS. everything working fine and in that i am using a custom directive to plot the chart using D3. I am adding the chart data in the controller itself by using  $scope.initially it will plot but i will change the data in one button click but the chart is not updating automatically,

after reading angularjs documentation i understand by using $scope we can able to change the UI content dynamically.whether it is possible here or any other scenario is present in angularJs

I am a beginner in AngularJS

```
  <div  data-ng-app="chartApp" data-ng-controller="SalesController">
  <h1>Today's Sales Chart</h1>
  <div linear-chart chart-data="salesData"></div>
  <button type="button" data-ng-click="Change()">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
```

My JS code

```
 var app = angular.module('chartApp', []);
    app.controller('SalesController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.salesData=[
    {hour: 1,sales: 54},
    {hour: 2,sales: 66},
    {hour: 3,sales: 77},
    {hour: 4,sales: 70},
    {hour: 5,sales: 60},
    {hour: 6,sales: 63},
    {hour: 7,sales: 55},
    {hour: 8,sales: 47},
    {hour: 9,sales: 55},
    {hour: 10,sales: 30}
];  
  $scope.Change = function () {
  //here i am changing the data so i need to replot the chart
  $scope.salesData=[
    {hour: 1,sales: 14},
    {hour: 2,sales: 16},
    {hour: 3,sales: 77},
    {hour: 4,sales: 10},
    {hour: 5,sales: 60},
    {hour: 6,sales: 63},
    {hour: 7,sales: 55},
    {hour: 8,sales: 47},
    {hour: 9,sales: 55},
    {hour: 10,sales: 30}
];
}  
}]);
//creating one custom directive to plot the chart
app.directive('linearChart', function($window){
  return{
  restrict:'EA',
  template:"<svg width='850' height='200'></svg>",
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
       var salesDataToPlot=scope[attrs.chartData];
       //if u gave like this u can remove attributr chart-data 
      // var salesDataToPlot=scope.salesData
       var padding = 20;
       var pathClass="path";
       var xScale, yScale, xAxisGen, yAxisGen, lineFun;

       var d3 = $window.d3;
       var rawSvg=elem.find('svg');
       var svg = d3.select(rawSvg[0]);

       function setChartParameters(){

           xScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([salesDataToPlot[0].hour, salesDataToPlot[salesDataToPlot.length-1].hour])
               .range([padding + 5, rawSvg.attr("width") - padding]);

           yScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(salesDataToPlot, function (d) {
                   return d.sales;
               })])
               .range([rawSvg.attr("height") - padding, 0]);

           xAxisGen = d3.svg.axis()
               .scale(xScale)
               .orient("bottom")
               .ticks(salesDataToPlot.length - 1);

           yAxisGen = d3.svg.axis()
               .scale(yScale)
               .orient("left")
               .ticks(5);

           lineFun = d3.svg.line()
               .x(function (d) {
                   return xScale(d.hour);
               })
               .y(function (d) {
                   return yScale(d.sales);
               })
               .interpolate("basis");
       }

     function drawLineChart() {

           setChartParameters();

           svg.append("svg:g")
               .attr("class", "x axis")
               .attr("transform", "translate(0,180)")
               .call(xAxisGen);

           svg.append("svg:g")
               .attr("class", "y axis")
               .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
               .call(yAxisGen);

           svg.append("svg:path")
               .attr({
                   d: lineFun(salesDataToPlot),
                   "stroke": "blue",
                   "stroke-width": 2,
                   "fill": "none",
                   "class": pathClass
               });
       }
       drawLineChart();
   }
  };
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/cpyx2tq9/1/)

Comment: I updated code and it seems to work when I print the data: http://jsfiddle.net/cpyx2tq9/3/

Comment: @Matheno: data will update but i need to update the chart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go a live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dc3efrc/1/

```
scope.$watch(attrs.chartData, function(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        svg.selectAll("*").remove();
        drawLineChart(newValue);
    }
}, true);
```

Use $watch method of scope to trigger update on model change. Also, don't forget to clear previous graph if you don't need it (svg.selectAll("*").remove()).

Please, see full example as I've made some minor modifications to your salesDataToPlot variable (it is now a function parameter).

Comment: Thanks...Working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$watch` on scope to listen to `salesData` data changes and rebuild your chart when it's done.

```
//...
scope.$watch('salesData', function (newSalesData){
    // drawLineChart();
    // redraw logic
});
//...
```